# ¿Puedo usar las propiedades del vue.config.js en mi App.vue o en main.js?

Tags: vue.js

tengo un proyecto en **Vue.js** y en **vue.config.js** he configurado el **publicPath**.

```
publicPath: '/front'
```

En el **main.js** tengo configurado **vue-router**:

```
const routes = [
    {name: 'home', path: '/front', component: Vacio},
    {name: 'holaMundo', path: '/front/holaMundo', component: HelloWorld},
    {name: 'personas', path: '/front/personas', component: Personas}
];
```

Y en mi **App.vue** utilizo **vue-router**:

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link class="nav-link" to="/front">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link class="nav-link" to="/front/holaMundo">Hola Mundo</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link class="nav-link" to="/front/personas">Personas</router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Lo que quiero es, **no tener que poner '/front' cada vez que utilice vue-router** ya que si mañana quiero cambiar la configuración de **publicPath** no tener que cambiar a mano todos los **/front**

¿Puedo usar las propiedades del vue.config.js en mi App.vue o en main.js?
Algo así:

```
const routes = [
    {name: 'home', path: vue.confug.publicPath, component: Vacio},
    {name: 'holaMundo', path: vue.confug.publicPath + '/front/holaMundo', component: HelloWorld},
    {name: 'personas', path: vue.confug.publicPath + '/front/personas', component: Personas}
];
```

(Estoy utilizando **vue.confug.publicPath** como una variable)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!